# Authentication for statistics.dislikeCount()

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

New to using the YouTube API/data scraping in general, and I was wondering exactly what the authentication for the statistics.dislikeCount() in the Videos section entails? Does it mean that we would have to obtain consent for each channel for which we want to view the dislike count individually? How would one go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

> **statistics.dislikeCount**
>
> **unsigned long**
>
> **Note:** The **statistics.dislikeCount** property was made private as of December 13,
> 2021. This means that the property is included in an API response only if the API request was authenticated by the video owner. See the
> revision history for more information.
>
> The number of users who have indicated that they disliked the video.
> Blockquote

Source: [videos#statistics.dislikeCount](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.dislikeCount)

So it's not just about consent as far as I understand, you have to be the owner of the YouTube channel to be able to retrieve the dislikes of its videos.